# Is it possible to run an Android instrumentation test with Appium?

Tags: android, appium, adb, benchmarking, android-instrumentation

Usually [Appium testing framework](http://appium.io/) is used to test Android/iOS **apps**. However i need to run an Android **instrumentation test** (apk, to be more detailed it's [Jetpack benchmarking apk](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/benchmark)), collect some results (JSON file on instrumented device) with Appium `AndroidDriver`.

I'm able to push apk to device and install it as Appium usually does with "app" capability and apk path passed. However i can't run the instrumentation with "mobile:shell" + "am instrument .. " because of the following exception:

```
Error in org.company.libcompany.benchmark.CoreClassLoadTimeBenchmark:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomationService android.accessibilityservice.IAccessibilityServiceClient$Stub$Proxy@ab1429calready registered!
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1691)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
    at android.app.IUiAutomationConnection$Stub$Proxy.connect(IUiAutomationConnection.java:239)
    at android.app.UiAutomation.connect(UiAutomation.java:223)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.getUiAutomation(Instrumentation.java:1919)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.getUiAutomation(Instrumentation.java:1876)
    at androidx.test.runner.permission.UiAutomationShellCommand.<init>(UiAutomationShellCommand.java:65)
    at androidx.test.runner.permission.PermissionRequester.addPermissions(PermissionRequester.java:92)
    at androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule.grantPermissions(GrantPermissionRule.java:100)
    at androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule.grant(GrantPermissionRule.java:94)
    at androidx.benchmark.junit4.BenchmarkRule.apply(BenchmarkRule.kt:171)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.applyAll(RunRules.java:26)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.<init>(RunRules.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.withTestRules(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:400)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.withRules(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:356)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:278)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1939)
```

I believe it happens as Appium already registered an instrumentation, thus failing now.

In general i need to run an instrumentation test and get a file from device. `ADB` commands are prohibited (as it's tested on device farm and custom instrumentation runner jar is provided).